# Getting a 'DeprecationWarning' error while creating an API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I am learning rest api but keep on getting the following error. Why? I am using Node JS, Mongo DB and Express. I am new to this.

Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localost/bookstore');
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Please use /api for the API.');
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Running on port 3000...');
```

Error:

```
(node:7908) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and wil
l be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrl
Parser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1360:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1401:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1485:7)
    at Function.listen (C:\apiproject\bookstore\node_modules\express\lib\applica
tion.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\apiproject\bookstore\app.js:14:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

Comment: If you have any other command prompts open wr you already started service stop them and re run the app

Comment: I think there's a typo in connection string instead of `localhost` it is `localost`.

Comment: There are two messages. One is the DeprecationWarning about mongoddb URL parser, which is just a warning and should be still working in current version. 
The other one is an error listen EADDRINUSE :::3000. It means port 3000, which you want to listen into,  is already in use. It is the one makes your program quit.

Answer (score 0):

The error is showing that port 3000 is already in use.

Please get the list of all the ports in use and then kill the port 3000 and run the application again

netstat -a -o to get all the running ports 
And then 
Taskkill /PID -f  (PID)